# Deployment Strategies

Tags: deployment

i need to evaluate Software Deployment Strategies but literature is lacking. So i thought i could ask you which Strategies you know / use so that i can pick them up and evaluate them.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you mean deploying on many computers within an organisation, or just in general?

Comment: Deploy what? Can you provide more details on what kind of applications you're referring to?

Comment: Your question is vague and ambiguous: deploy *what*? I am inclined to vote for closing this question as an exact duplicate, but it is too ambiguous to actually be a duplicate of anything. http://imgur.com/bzmFS

Comment: xcopy. Seriously man, deploy what to where? A little more information would be helpful.

Comment: This depends on what you want to deploy. Some more specifics would help. Are you worried about the technical or business aspects?

Comment: Im refering to technical aspects. Such as Deployment of Software through for example Active Directory or Virtual Desktops etc. That means technical possibilities to transfer and install Software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want a strategy? Deployment is more tactically and operational driven than strategic. From a software quality point of view, early feedback is seen as important and is driving towards an ASAP strategy. Take a look at the work of [Kent Beck](http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/blog/?p=566) and google on lean startups. [A thought experiment](http://www.threeriversinstitute.org/blog/?p=488). Depending on your capital situation, market and competitors, you might prefer an ALAP strategy. But most companies are not Apple.